# missing socket.io.js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

when starting app.js I get

$ node app.js
info: socket.io started

however, running index.html it says that it's missing

```
 GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found) localhost:5
 Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
```

I used npm install socket.io express

app.js

```
 var express = require('express')
   , http = require('http');

 var io = require('socket.io');

 var app = express()
   , server = require('http').createServer(app)
   , io = io.listen(server);

 app.configure(function(){
   app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
   app.use(express.bodyParser());
 });

 io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
   socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
   socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
     console.log(data);
   });
 });
```

index.html

```
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 <script>
   var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
   socket.on('news', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
   socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
   });
  </script>
```

Comment: Where did you get the client-side script for socket.io? you might not have the right one.

Comment: @SamT, the client-side script comes bundled with the socket-io package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks a bit messed up. Got it to work by changing it to this:

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , app = express()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
  ;

app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Comment: Unless I am missing something here, your code is also a bit messed up. ;P In the variable declaration you have commas at the end of each line, and on the beginning of each line.