# another /socket.io/socket.io.js 404

Tags: express, socket.io

my client side app.html:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://mywebsite.com/');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

my serverside app.js:

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8888);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/app.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

if I go to http://mywebsite.com:8888 the console reads:

```
Object {hello: "world"}
```

but if I go to http://mywebsite.com/app.html the console reads:

```
GET http://mywebsite.com/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
```

as refired to here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10192084/990434 I have express v3.1.1, i've also tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14167488/990434 to no avail. I have tried some other random things from a google group that I can't seem to find in my long messy history. any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing files stored on your server and routes that your server serves. Although `app.html` is a file on your server, your server does not respond to requests to `/app.html`. Instead, when a request comes to `/`, then your server sends the file `app.html`. In fact, the client/recipient will never know that the file that it receives was called `app.html` on your server. So when a client (browser) goes to `http://mywebsite.com:8888` then they get the html file that has the `script` tags. Those `script` tags have code that makes your browser connect to socket.io which is programmed to, on `'connection'`, send a message to the client:

```
socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
```

The client code running in your browser then receives the message

```
socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
```

and then sends a message back to the server

```
socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
```

Everything is working as programmed. However, there is no 'router' on your server listening to requests to `/app.html`